# how to set up variable in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, google-chrome-extension

HTML:

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="url" id= "url"name="url"class="url" placeholder="URL"required
</form>

<iframe class = "website" name = "website" src=  ></iframe>
```

how to make the source equal to a variable that can be changed by clicking enter after typing URL

This is for a website so javascript and CSS are also involved.
I completely new to coding, it will be very helpful if you guys could explain how it works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a go with this

I closed the input tag for you

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => { // on page load
  document.getElementById("urlForm").addEventListener("submit", (e) => { // on submit/enter
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    let url = document.getElementById("url").value;
    document.getElementById("website").src = url;
  });
});
```

```css
iframe {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
```

```html
<form id="urlForm">
  <input type="url" id="url" name="url" class="url" placeholder="URL" required />
</form>

<iframe class="website" id="website"></iframe>
```

jQuery:

```js
$(function() { // page load
  $("#urlForm").on("submit", (e) => { // on submit/enter
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    let url = $("#url").val();
    $("#website").attr("src", url);
  });
});
```

```css
iframe {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="urlForm">
  <input type="url" id="url" name="url" class="url" placeholder="URL" required />
</form>

<iframe class="website" id="website"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here if you'r using JQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#url').keyup(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode == 13)
      {
          $("iframe").attr('src',$(this).val())
      }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
    <input type="url" id="url" name="url" class="url" placeholder="URL" required
  </form>
  <br/>
<iframe class = "website" name = "website" src=""></iframe>
```

Comment: Why use keyup when you have a form?